# Elasticsearch and jhipster

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jhipster

I am using jhipster generated application with MySQL database. My application is deployed on tomcat with nginx on Ubuntu 18.04 (.war file generated with mvnw package -Pprod). To deploy I used the .war.orig file.

On Ubuntu server I've insttalled the elasticsearch just like described in a guide here (I used elasticsearch version 6.3): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-16-04

Whereas the /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml file looks like this:

```
network.host: localhost
http.port: 9200
```

In application-prod.yml I have following elasticsearch configuration:

```
    data:
    elasticsearch:
        cluster-name:
        cluster-nodes: localhost:9200
```

When I deploy the app on tomcat the following error occurs:

```
2018-06-17 22:58:49.675 ERROR 28733 --- [1-8080-exec-161] o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait      : Internal Server Error

org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

The application is working, but every request (except for logging in) to the backend results in an internal server error 500.

The command `curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'` gives a proper return.

Have I misconfigured anything?

Comment: What version JHipster are you using?  The correct Elasticsearch version to use depends on the spring-data-elasticsearch library.  In JHipster v4, it was 2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple solutions, I have finally given up.

Turns out that the quickest (and possibly the only working) solution is to set up the elasticsearch by `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/elasticsearch.yml up` (of course you can also buy a dedicated solution for that, which I wanted to avoid).

The application-prod.yml configuration remained as I posted above.

FYI: remember to recreate the database and redeploy the app after setting the elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
data:
    elasticsearch:
        cluster-name: <cluster_name>
        cluster-nodes: <usually it is same as cluster name, default qSea>
        properties:
            host: <ip address>
            user: <username:password>
            port: 9300
            enableSsl: false
            path:
                logs: target/elasticsearch/log
                data: target/elasticsearch/data
```

Also, i guess you are communicating over transport layer. You can build the transport client using this method (you can change it if x-pack is not installed):

```
private static TransportClient buildTransPortClient() {

    String host = "<IP Address>";
    int port = 9300; // port is 9300 not 9200

    Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("client.transport.nodes_sampler_interval", "5s")
            .put("client.transport.sniff", false).put("transport.tcp.compress", true).put("cluster.name", "<cluster_name>")
            .put("xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled", false).put("request.headers.X-Found-Cluster", "<cluster_name>")
            .put("xpack.security.user", "<user_name and password. by default it is elastic:changeme (of course if you have installed x-pack)>").build();

    TransportClient client = null;

    try {
        client = new PreBuiltXPackTransportClient(settings);

        for (InetAddress address : InetAddress.getAllByName(host)) {
            if ((address instanceof Inet6Address) || (address instanceof Inet4Address)) {
                client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(address, port));
            }
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to get the host" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception aaya hai");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return client;
}
```

and then can test. If this is working then your jhipster application is working well with elasticsearch.

Comment: Should I have a cluster name specified or can I leave it blank like in a default config?